# Mandatory Chrome Policies on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, group-policy, defaults

I'm trying to install a private Chrome extension on OS X by modifying Chrome policies. I was able to do this successfully on Windows by editing the relevant HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry, but on OS X I'm having problems.

Using the following commands, the policies show up in chrome://policy but have a "recommended" level instead of "mandatory" on Windows.

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallSources -array "http://install-url.com/*"
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallWhitelist -array "chrome-extension-id"
```

Whenever I attempt to install the extension, Chrome instead just downloads the file and presents a message that Apps, Scripts, and Extensions cannot be installed from this Website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post, but it came up in a google search and there wasn't an answer here.

The answer to this question after some troubleshooting is as follows:

The file that contains policies that are **Recommended** is

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
```

The commands you posted would modify this file if run in the user context

In order to have **Mandatory** you need to have your Mac managed, by say JAMF or Munki. Once your Mac is managed you can use plists in

```
/Library/Managed Preferences/
```

&

```
/Library/Managed Preferences/$user
```

Effectively this moves com.google.Chrome.plist from the user context to the machine context. HKCU vs HKLM

The documentation here talks about this more under **Debugging**
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start

Comment: It would appear you would have to deploy a system profile with a payload to override Chrome policies locally with the Mandatory status. You don't need to have any configured management software, but be able to generate a .mobileconfig file with the payload and then use /usr/bin/profiles -I -F /path/to/Google Chrome.mobileconfig

Comment: @vgrsec I am trying to force install an extension in Chrome. I edited the property list at /Library/Managed Preferences/username/com.google.Chrome.plist. I added a dictionary under Root –> ExtensionSettings. Unfortunately, I don't see this at chrome://policy. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, the policies for the extension are given in [Configuring Apps and Extensions by Policy](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions).

As stated:

> The policies for the extension can be configured via MCX preferences for the `com.google.Chrome.extensions.gihmafigllmhbppdfjnfecimiohcljba` bundle, or for the `org.chromium.Chromium.extensions.gihmafigllmhbppdfjnfecimiohcljba` bundle if using Chromium.

The complete configuration procedure can be found in the given documentation.

Comment: That's not really relevant. This explains how to configure managed storage for extensions, but not how to configure the global browser policy (which is needed here).